# jquery mobile css always overwrites my css

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I'm loading my css after jQuery Mobile's css file:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=".../1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
</head>
```

But my margin attribute always get overwritten:

[image: firebug showing overwritten margin attribute]

Is jquery's css getting loaded dynamically after mine somehow?
I've tried using [ThemeRoller](http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/) but it is too simple, I can't change the margins.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your CSS is getting overwritten is because the jQuery's CSS is more accurate with its selectors.

You say that all items with class `.ui-radio` should have margin, which is taken first, then all items with .ui-radio that are inside .ui-controlgroup-vertical have a set margin too.

A simple trick would be to make sure to use the same selector, `.ui-controlgroup-vertical .ui-radio` in this case, this should do the trick if your CSS is loaded after. Else, use one more parent container and you will be fine.

Little read to make it clearer: http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Training/Priority_level_of_selector